# GUI responds very slow ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04

My ubuntu system GUI became very slow. Not sure of the reason for it.
[image]

The issue could be with the graphic drivers. How do I resolve it.

```
glxinfo | grep Mesa
client glx vendor string: Mesa Project and SGI
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.0.0
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 18.0.0.
```

I did a fresh install of  Ubuntu 18.04.3 64 bit . thought that would resolve the issue but not really.

System is running on dual boot , windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04.

Post fresh installation of Ubuntu, when I try to login  UI freezes . I had to follow instructions mentioned [here](https://youtu.be/Tg4fWsFPzSE) to get post login. But the UI is too lagging to use.

output:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo lshw -C display
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Cape Verde XT [Radeon HD 7770/8760 / R7 250X]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f7000000-f703ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:f7040000-f705ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

Running Ubuntu from live USB: Detects the Intel graphics
[image: lIVE_USB_UBUNTU]

Comment: I think llvmpipe indicates that you have a very slow way to display the graphics. Maybe you can find a proprietary graphics driver to make it more responsive. What brand and model is your graphics chip?

Comment: Maybe this command can help: `sudo lshw -C display`

Comment: There seems to be an issue with  installation, with the live USB stick, Ubuntu UI was real response. Post installation, the complete GUI is laggy.

Comment: I have  AMD Radeon R7 250X graphic card.

Comment: I know Intel and nvidia graphics but have not much experience of Radeon graphics. I thought that there are rather good built-in linux drivers for Radeon nowadays. How new is that Radeon R7 250X graphic card? If rather new, you may have better luck with the newest Ubuntu version, 19.10, because its linux kernel has drivers for newer hardware (than the older kernels (that are available in 18.04.3 LTS). Otherwise it is a good idea to stay with the LTS releases.

Comment: R7 250X is a old one launched around 2014.

Comment: When installing, at the window 'Updates and other software', did you select (tick) 'Installl third-party software for graphics and Wi-Fi hardware and additional media formats'? In that case, try installing without selecting it. And vice versa: If you did not select it, try selecting it and installing.

Comment: Yes I did that, the problem is with the graphics card , it's not working in windows as well (even after installing the AMD driver ). I guess it reached it EOL. :( Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry to read that the card stopped working. Thanks for telling use how the issue was resolved.